# Setting up a subdomain for email sending on AWS Route 53 with CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, cname

Hi So I am getting a bit confused although I know this shouldn't be as complicated.

Currently there is this issue with some DNS providers (mine is network solutions), that does not take in underscores "_" in its CNAME records, the DKIM CNAME produced by Amazon SES does however, require underscores in it.

So in order for this to work I can move the entire DNS to be hosted on Route 53, but if I don't want to that, and just want to create a subdomain for email sending and delegate it to Route53, how exactly would I be able to do that?

I have created a host zone in Route 53 with the domain name say domain.com (DNS currently hosted with network solutions), now how would I create a subdomain? and what exactly should I put under the create new record set?

anyone can give me some advises thanks alot!

Comment: You can delegate the control of just the subdomain to AWS-Route53 then manage the records on AWS. However, you cannot add a CNAME for the root. By the way, I'm slightly confused regarding the need of subdomain for sending emails.

Comment: @RakeshBollampally hi thanks for your response!Could you maybe give me a bit more detail on how to do that? Well I currently have the CNAME by Amazon SES for DKIM, its suppose to be added to the DNS side (which I have with network solutions), but they do not allow underscores input so it won't work. 
And so I am trying to set a subdomain for email sending and delegate to Route53, which it allows underscores input for CNAME. But not exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: In AWS route 53, create a new hosted for subdomain.domain.com. Get the delegation set. In Network Solutions management area, create a sub domain subdomain.domain.com. Add route53 delegation set name records for this subdomain. Now, you can manage the subdomain from Route53.

Comment: @RakeshBollampally thanks for response, right now I have a subdomain name host zone set up in route53, and I see the 4 delegation set. My question is, in network solutions, do I add these delegation set ns in the CNAME records? with alias being my subdomain name and other host as in the NS names? so do I repeat the steps four times with same subdomain name to assign to four different delegation set NS?

Comment: No, it should be NS record. Not A or CNAME. Some DNS providers might not give you this option for sub-domains. In that case, you may have to host the root domain on Route 53 too.

Comment: @RakeshBollampally yeah I got pretty confused. in network solutions, there is also the DNS, where I can enter the NS. But then if I enter the NS, my domain name NS will be pointed and moved to route 53. but I only want the subdomain name to be moved over not my parent domain name. And on network solutions documentation it says to create a subdomain is to enter one under its A record with a IP address provided where it can point to. But no NS.. so I do not know what I can do at this point..

Comment: @RakeshBollampally do you know if maybe I can convert the NS delegation set in route 53 to an IP address or something? then I could use that info to put under A Record in network solutions or something.. if not then I guess I will have to host the entire DNS on route 53?

Comment: It is not about IP address or a Canonical name. NS records are completely different from CNAME records and A records. NS records delegate control while A, CNAME and MX records are used to point a domain/subdomain to IP address. Do you have loads of records for your root domain?

Comment: @RakeshBollampally I see, so my only option now really is to move the root domain entirely, I have quiet a few records, but just didn't want to go through the propagation downtime for website and mail server during the move.

Comment: If you recreate the records first in Route 53 then switch the DNS authority, there should not be any down time.